# TypeScript extended Class first argument not set/display

Tags: typescript, class, extends

I just getting started with TS and play now with classes.
I have this fairly simple example, but do not see, why when I console.log the properties of new Car "merced" I can see the string color, but not the number of wheels.

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor(public color: string) {}

  honk(): void {
    console.log('Meep')
  }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
  constructor(public wheels: number, color: string) {
    super(color);
  }
}

const merced = new Car(2, 'red');
console.log(merced.color)
console.log(merced.wheels)
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmALAlqe0DeAoa1gHsA7CAFwCcBXYE-MgCgAcKAjEVPfEWgLmlLOSEA5gEpMAXyw5oiIgGs6I3gDd8yACaZpuAsU7wAdFyF0A5AFl48BqZHTJk0JBgBhMGWjwAHiXiF1MAgoaFo6RPxUNPRMrOwA7ohWIBC8hBQAtszwZAA0HFxkvPyCoqG4fBQM2XQEBSIA3PZYkli6pNDp2cDwmgC80ITwcdBu9ABMeaZkPbaNbfpG+CadZN3qBrW0dvMghsZ0K2sGCUkQIkA

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for checking.
I Have not doubted the console ... I ran it with ts-node in vscodes terminal ... what could that be.